# no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::ostream << Dual

Tags: c++

I am getting trouble to output the object. I get an error in "cout << sum;" line. How can I print this Dual Number Object as D(float, float).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dual{
    public:
        float val, eps;
        Dual(float v, float e){
            val = v;
            eps = e;
        }

        Dual operator+(Dual const &obj) {
            Dual res(0, 0);
            res.val = val + obj.val;
            res.eps = eps + obj.eps;
            return res;
        }

        void print() const { 
            cout << "Dual(" << val << ", " << eps << endl; 
        }
};

int main(){
    Dual d1(1, 2), d2(4, 5);
    Dual sum = d1 + d2;
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to call `sum.print()` ?

Comment: Otherwise you need to create your own operator <<() for your class like this example: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160) however then what is the purpose of the print() member if you are not going to use it.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? How does `std::cout` know how to print a `Dual`? You need to define `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Dual& d)`

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```cpp
        void print() const { 
            cout << "Dual(" << val << ", " << eps << endl; 
        }
```

to something like this:

```cpp
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Dual const &d) { 
            os << "Dual(" << d.val << ", " << d.eps << ")"; 
            return os;
        }
```

... and off you go. Note that I've intentionally omitted printing a new-line as part of printing the `Dual` object. Oh, and when you want a new-line, just use `"\n"`, not `std::endl`, which (at least IMO) was kind of a mistake and should be avoided in general.

Comment: Using a hidden `friend` function like this is far superior to an otherwise free function. Making this a hidden friend means that `cout << SomethingNotADual{}` won't consider it in overload resolution, improving performance and also meaning that GCC won't show this overload in its long error messages where it shows every "Considered this overload, but it didn't work because ...".

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined an `operator<<` for `Dual`, that is why you are getting the error.  You do, however, have a `print()` method implemented, but you are not using it.

So, you can either:

- simply change `cout << sum;` to `sum.print();`

```cpp
int main(){
    Dual d1(1, 2), d2(4, 5);
    Dual sum = d1 + d2;
    sum.print();
    return 0;
}
```

- otherwise, implement `operator<<`:

```cpp
class Dual{
    public:
        float val, eps;
        ...
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Dual const &obj) { 
    os << "Dual(" << obj.val << ", " << obj.eps << endl;
    return os;
}
```

If you still want to use `print()`, you should change it to take an `ostream` as input:

```cpp
class Dual{
    public:
        float val, eps;

        ...

        void print(ostream &os) const { 
            os << "Dual(" << val << ", " << eps << endl; 
        }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Dual const &obj)
{
    obj.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Then, you can use either of these:

```cpp
cout << sum;
```

```cpp
sum.print(cout);
```